# A few questions on IDataErrorInfo Interface

Tags: .net-core, idataerrorinfo

I've looked at a few examples of implementing the `IDataErrorInfo` interface and all of those implemented that somewhat like this:

```
public string Error => null;
public string this[string columnName] {
    get {
        string res = null;
        switch (columnName) {
            case "FirstName":
                if (FirstName != "test") res = "First Name Invalid!";
                break;
            case "LastName":
                if (LastName != "test") res = "Last Name Invalid!";
                break;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

What's the purpose of `public string Error` and how to use that instead of returning `null`? In `xaml` some of those examples used a predefined style targeting `TextBox` and others used a `Label` or `ToolTip` like these:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Fname" 
         Text="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
         ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=Fname, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />

<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=Fname, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
```

Can I avoid `x:Name="Fname"` and `ElementName=Fname` when it's used as a `ToolTip` and shorten the expression `(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent`?

---

**EDIT**

Probably `DataAnnotations` is the most elegant way to to validate individual property as well as the whole model/viewmodel along with these:

```
public string Error => null;
public string this[string columnName] {
    get {
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (Validator.TryValidateProperty(
            GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(this), 
            new ValidationContext(this) { MemberName = columnName }, 
            validationResults
            )) return null;

        return validationResults.First().ErrorMessage;
    }
}
```

To validate the whole model I just am supposed to call:

```
Validator.TryValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this), null, true);
```

in `CanExecute` of `ICommand`. This example also didn't use the `public string Error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Error` property is ignored by the WPF binding engine so you only have to care about to implement the indexer.

By the way, it's recommended to implement and use the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface instead of `IDataErrorInfo` since .NET Framework 4.5.